# .NET Core запускаемое приложение

Tags: .net

Я правильно понимаю, что на выходе платформы `.NET Core` получается `dll`, которую затем необходимо на клиентской платформе скормить консольной утилите для запуска?

Иными словами, если я захочу на `LINUX` сделать ярлык для своей программы, то должен в ярлык поместить вызов `dotnet [путь к DLL]` или какая-то компиляция в исполняемый файл целевой платформы все таки есть?

Comment: да.............

Comment: Если Вы указываете RID целевой платформы, то при сборке должен включатся нативный исполняемый файл для этой платформы.